# Show authors of .pbxproj, .xib, .storyboard in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, xcode11

Is it possible to show Authors in files that are not `.swift`, `.m`, `.h` etc. in Xcode 11+?

For example `.pbxproj`, or `.xib` or `.storyboard` Interface Builder files.

"Show Authors" via <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> is not working, as it does for text source files.